# SapUI5 UI Controls Size Issue

Tags: sapui5

I would like to make responsive (combobox,input etc.) ui controls in sapui5. But on the web environment some of components such as combobox and input are looking so large. I've uploaded an image regarding to this problem. How can I change view sizes of these ui controls ? Is there a simple way to do this like using sap.m.size ? I hope I made make myself clear.
Here is the link of image;
https://ibb.co/dJBdVx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's event simplier than resizing each control to a given size...

SAPUI5 has a feature called 'content density' mode. Which stablishes the controls/paddings/margins sizes depending on the selected mode.

There are 2 main modes. 'Cozy' which is the large one, and it is meant for touchable devices (your finger is a thick pointer) and 'compact' for desktop devices (with a mouse you can point accurately).

So all you need to do is setting one of this modes based on the device.
[Here the tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579) to know how to do it.

And [here the documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e54f729da8e3405fae5e4fe8ae7784c1) about the 'content density'

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day :) I just learned cozy and compact modes. Is it possible to apply compact mode whole project ? Do I need to define this style definition in every view "sapUiSizeCompact" ?

Comment: apply it ly decribed [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579)... usualy you have a main view wrapping all your views, and do navigation properly. In the documentation tutorials is App.view.xml with its controller App.controller.js... Apply the class to it and it will be propagated to the inner controls... Other solution, could be applying the class to the <body> tag of your index.html file...